# How to Output a Js Function Twice on the same page

Tags: javascript, html

Hello here I'm trying to Output my function on two separate divs in my project but if I simply output the same I'd it cancels the whole code and nulls the output here is the code.

```
<script>
function randomString() {
            //initialize a variable having alpha-numeric characters
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

            //specify the length for the new string to be generated
    var string_length = 10;
    var randomstring = '';

            //put a loop to select a character randomly in each iteration
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
             //display the generated string 
    document.getElementById("randomfield").innerHTML = randomstring;
}
</script>
```

Then on the body I use

```
<body onload="randomString();">

<div>
<p id="randomfield"></p>
</div>
</body>
```

The thing is I want to Output the same string on the page but on a different div maybe at the footer but if I proceed to add

```
<body onload="randomString();">


<div>
<p id="randomfield"></p>
</div>

<hr>
<footer>

<p id="randomfield"></p>

</footer>

</body>
```

On the same page it cancels the whole code and nullifies the output. How do I fix this i barely have knowledge of Js

Comment: The problem here is you have the same id twice which is invalid html. Maybe use a class instead?

Comment: Please change your keyboard to write only single `s` and `r` :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same `id` in both areas. You have to specify different id to have them work:

```js
function randomSSSSSString() {
  //initialize a variable having alpha-numeric characters
  var charssssss = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  //specify the length for the new string to be generated
  var sssssstring_length = 10;
  var randomsssssstring = '';

  //put a loop to select a character randomly in each iteration
  for (var i = 0; i < sssssstring_length; i++) {
    var rrrrrrnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * charssssss.length);
    randomsssssstring += charssssss.substring(rrrrrrnum, rrrrrrnum + 1);
  }
  //display the generated string 
  document.getElementById("rrrrrrandomfield").innerHTML = randomsssssstring;
  document.getElementById("rrrrrrandomfield2").innerHTML = randomsssssstring;
}
```

```html
<body onload="randomSSSSSString();">
  <div>
    <p id="rrrrrrandomfield"></p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <footer>
    <p id="rrrrrrandomfield2"></p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Now i just learned something new from your comments, thanks alot I wish I could learn javascript in full but DIY is quite hard

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're using same "**id**" more than once, which is not valid.

You can change the **id** to class instead and can use **querySelectorAll** to loop through each element consisting of that class to display your result.

```js
function randomSSSSSString() {
            //initialize a variable having alpha-numeric characters
    var charssssss = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

            //specify the length for the new string to be generated
    var sssssstring_length = 10;
    var randomsssssstring = '';

            //put a loop to select a character randomly in each iteration
    for (var i=0; i<sssssstring_length; i++) {
        var rrrrrrnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * charssssss.length);
        randomsssssstring += charssssss.substring(rrrrrrnum,rrrrrrnum+1);
    }
             //display the generated string 
       var i_want_show_here = document.querySelectorAll(".rrrrrrandomfield")
       Array.prototype.forEach.call(i_want_show_here, function(el) {
        el.innerHTML = randomsssssstring
      });
}
```

```html
<body onload="randomSSSSSString();">




<div>
<p class="rrrrrrandomfield"></p>
</div>

<hr>
<footer>

<p class="rrrrrrandomfield"></p>

</footer>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this by creating dynamic `p` tag with same id. There is no `var` datatype in javascript change it to `let`.

```js
function randomString() {
    let characters = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    let randnum = document.getElementById("randnum") 

    let stringLength = 10;
    let tempRandomString = '';
    
    for (let i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
        let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length);
        tempRandomString += characters.substring(randNum, randNum + 1);
    }
    
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        const elem = document.createElement(`p`);
        elem.id = tempRandomString;
        elem.innerText= tempRandomString;
        randnum.appendChild(elem);
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <title>Web Page</title>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body onload="randomString();">

    <div id="randnum">

    </div>
  </body> 
</html>
```